# Having issues with Datetime Format

Tags: python

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

file = open('RTWR.csv', newline ='')
routed = csv.reader(file)

header = next(routed) #header 
data = []
for row in routed:
    #row = ['PostDate', 'RouteID', 'DriverID', 'Name', 'Address', 'City', 'State', 'Zip','CustID','CompletedTime','ArrivalTime']
    Post_Date = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%m/%d/%Y') # converting the rows to their approriate data types for simpler parsing later
    Route_ID = str(row[1])
    Driver_ID = str(row[2])
    Name = str(row[3])
    Address = str(row[4])
    City = str(row[5])
    State = str(row[6])
    Zip = str(row[7])
    Cust_ID = str(row[8])
    Completed_time = datetime.strptime(row[9], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p') 
   ''' Ct = datetime.strptime(Completed_time, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p") #tried creating a new variable same issue '''
    Arrival_time = str(row[10])

    data.append([Post_Date,Route_ID,Driver_ID,Name,Address,City,State,Zip,Cust_ID,Arrival_time,Completed_time])
```

The value of Completed_time looks like this ---> `11/17/2019 5:46:48 PM`

I keep getting the following Error below:

```
raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p'
```

is the format I'm using wrong, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: And include the entire error stack, it will contain additional information that is critical in figuring out the problem.

Comment: Then why don't you use `pandas` given that are working with tabular data?

Comment: "time data '' does not match format" This says you are trying to parse an empty string as a time. The error message will have more information that points to the exact line that causes the error. Then you need to determine why the string is empty when you aren't expecting it to be.